# PXE boot not happening - Please advise

Tags: linux, pxe-boot

Hi we are trying to PXE boot but it says ---->

PXE-E61 : Media test failure , check cable
PXE-M0F : Exiting Broadcom PXE ROM .

What should we check for ?

Thanks
Nishant

Comment: The cable was not connected to the correct NIC it was given to NIC 2 instaed of NIC 1 . Thanks for the pointers .

Comment: So you mean it works now? In this case, can you close the question?

Answer (score 5):

"Media test failure", as emphasized by "check cable" means that there is no link detected on the local NIC.

Do you have the link led on for this machine ? If so, you might assume a buggy PXE/bios rom. If not, make a physical fix.

Answer (score 1):

Is the cable okay?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're trying to netboot a netbook via Wi-Fi — forget it!

Generally, this means PXE BootLoader can use no network connection. Check your cable.